# Mesh partitioning with METIS

Tags: finite-element, graph-theory

I am trying to use METIS-5.1.0 edition in order to partion a FE mesh. For demostration purposes I created  2x2 rectangle mesh and tried to partition it. However, I notice a weird behaviour in my code. When i am using 2 parts to partion the mesh everything works file, but if i increase the number of partions at 3 or 4 I am not getting what I expect. For example for partioning parts=4 I get {0,0,2,2} as partitioing output, while I expect something like {0,1,2,3}.Any idea why is this happening?

Here is my example code:
[image]

Comment: METIS doesn't find the *exact* best partition. I would have assumed that it does in your case, but I don't think it guarantees an exact solution. What happens if you use many many more nodes you want to partition?

Comment: using more Q4 elements( for example 9 elements) the results look logical for larger number od partitions.However, if the number of parts is close to the total number of elements (for example i have 9 elements and i need 6 parts) same bahaviour occurs.

Comment: You might want to contact the developer of METIS, George Karypis, if this is an important feature to you.